# How to retrieve right listbox and submit the form in struts 1.2

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, struts, struts-1

I needed to implement double list box control in struts 1.2 . As OptionTransferSelect control is not available in Struts 1.2 and I know Struts 1.x support is EOL but I need to change in current environment :( , I made the Two List box from struts UI tag and transfer the element with help of Javascript

Code

```
<td align="left" style="height:40" width="30%">Select Site:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="right" width="58%">
 <html-el:select name="myForm"  property="city" size="10" multiple="true">

                    <html-el:option value="">&nbsp;</html-el:option>
                    <html-el:option value="ALL">-- ALL --</html-el:option>
                    <html-el:options collection="cityList" property="itemValue" labelProperty="itemDescription"/>
                </html-el:select>
</td>
<td valign="middle">
<a href="#" onclick="listbox_moveacross('selectedSiteId', 'destinationID')">>></a>
<br/>
<a href="#" onclick="listbox_moveacross('destinationID', 'selectedSiteId')"><<</a>
</td>
<td align="right" style="height:40" width="30%">Selected Site:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<SELECT id="destinationID" size="10" multiple>
    <OPTION value="a">-----Select Value From city----</OPTION>
</SELECT>
</td>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" style="height:40" width="30%"></td>
      <html-el:submit styleClass="standardButton" property="submitAction">
      <bean-el:message key="save Button"/>
      </html-el:submit> <br />
      <br /> </td>
  </tr>
```

My Java script code is working fine ,But I want If user select Submit button , then selected List from destinationID List will go to form and I can use it .
But I am not able to set the destinationID List into FOrm Bean.

My JavaScript Code

```
 function listbox_moveacross(sourceID,destID){
    var src=document.getElementById(sourceID);
    var dest=document.getElementById(destID);

    var picked1 = false;
    for(var count=0;count<src.options.length;count++){
        if(src.options[count].selected==true){picked1=true;}
    }

    if(picked1==false){alert("Please select an option to move.");return;}

    for(var count=0;count<src.options.length;count++){
        if(src.options[count].selected==true){var option=src.options[count];
            var newOption=document.createElement("option");
            newOption.value=option.value;
            newOption.text=option.text;
            newOption.selected=true;
            try{dest.add(newOption,null);
            src.remove(count,null);
        }
            catch(error){dest.add(newOption);src.remove(count);
        }
        count--;
        }
    }}
```

Thanks in advance , Do tell me If I need to provide any more information

Comment: Why did you tag this Struts2 if it's about Struts1 ? Also [Struts1 is dead LONG time ago](https://struts.apache.org/struts1eol-announcement.html), I strongly suggest you to stop using it, and to consider migrating legacy projects, especially if they need to be evoluted and not only maintained

Comment: I tagged Struts2 becuase if someone who has currently working on struts2 and has Idea about Struts 1.x can answer this. I can understand and even i have mentioned that Struts 1.x is obeselete but unfortunately I need to  fix in Struts 1.2 . My bad

Comment: You're right, I skimmed the EOL part. BTW tag it "struts" in this case, because is usually monitored by struts2 users. Tagging "struts2" if it's not Struts2 is wrong.